# What is the difference between a loop and a natural loop?

Tags: compilers, loops, imperative-programming

Is there a difference between a loop and a natural loop?  Natural loops are defined as having a back edge to a head block that dominates it.  If you have a natural loop nested inside of another natural loop, does this mean the actual loop is the merging of these two natural loops?

I'm curious to know if there's an agreed upon distinction between a natural loop and a loop.

Comment: Please name the work this terminology is from. I've never heard of *natural loops* or *head blocks*.

Comment: @reinierpost Natural loop is a term from control flow analysis.  You can find it described here: http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/lecture-notes/Columbia-COMS-W4117/07-09-27.html

I'm wondering if there's an agreed upon distinction between a loop and a natural loop.